# ImageMagick / Ghostscript - Read Postscript Image Compile Error

Tags: xcode, imagemagick, ghostscript, postscript

I'm trying to read a postscript image using ImageMagick, which requires the Ghostscript package. I've install both and their dependencies using Homebrew and they have been link on Xcode. However, I get an error when calling the read function:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
using namespace Magick;

void DC_menu() {
InitializeMagick("");
string file = root + "Discrete Continuum/Slices/";
char temp_file[64];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
sprintf(temp_file,"%s%i.ps",file.c_str(),i);
contour_3D(temp_file); // Creates postscript image
Image contour_image;
contour_image.read("%c",temp_file); // Error occurs here
}
}
```

The error itself reads:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Magick::ErrorDelegate: Vascular-Flow: FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs' -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' -g612x792  '-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-77074KMn8mzeAGzn%d' '-f/var/tmp/magick-7707HwWtukv1jG0Q' '-f/var/tmp/magick-7707rg0uO65uSZh7' -c showpage' (-1) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/462

Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely it simply couldn't find Ghostscript. You will need to add the path of the Ghostscript executable to your $PATH environment variable.

Comment: If you installed ghostscript via homebrew, the additional part you need on your PATH will likely be `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Xcode is linked to the appropriate Homebrew folders, I don't have any problems with any other libraries I'm using. I have tried reinstalling ImageMagick ('brew reinstall imagemagick --with-ghostscript') but still have the same problem.